# Dynamically Added Html Inputs Page Tab Button Not Working

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, html

**I am adding dynamic HTML content to my pop up showing in below**

```
$.get(url, function (data) {
    swal({
        title: "",
        text: data,
        html: true,
        showCancelButton: false,
        showConfirmButton: false,
        customClass: "dialog",
        allowOutsideClick: true,
        allowEscapeKey: true
    },
    function() {
        console.log('');
    });
```

**Here is my dynamicHtml Content**

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm("GetSendMessagePopUp", "Help", FormMethod.Post, new {enctype = "multipart/form-data", id = "questionModelForm"}))
    {
        <div>
            @Html.TextBoxFor(item => item.FullName, new { style = "display: block"})
        </div>
        <div>            
            @Html.TextBoxFor(item => item.Phone, new {style = "display: block"})
        </div>
        <div>            
            @Html.TextAreaFor(item => item.Message, new {style = "display: block"})
        </div>

        <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="sendUserMessage()" class="helpButton">Gönder</a>
    }
</div>
```

Everything works fine except tab button not working to focus another field.

I tried in developer panel below but still not working

```
$('.dialog input').tabs();
$('.dialog input').tabs('refresh');
```

Comment: If the events should be triggered on the generated html content, then you might wanna use delegated events

Comment: @AhsN event can be triggered anywhere

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From sweetalert.js I commented defaults for tab key then it started working well

```
// TAB
    if (btnIndex === -1) {
        // No button focused. Jump to the confirm button.
        $targetElement = $okButton;
    } else {
        // Cycle to the next button
        if (btnIndex === $modalButtons.length - 1) {
            $targetElement = $modalButtons[0];
        } else {
            $targetElement = $modalButtons[btnIndex + 1];
        }
    }

    _stopEventPropagation$fireClick.stopEventPropagation(e);
    $targetElement.focus();

    if (params.confirmButtonColor) {
        _setFocusStyle.setFocusStyle($targetElement, params.confirmButtonColor);
    }
```

I removed this line than it works fine

Answer (score 1):

Add this piece of code too:

```
$.ajaxComplete(function () {
  $('.dialog input').tabs();
  $('.dialog input').tabs('refresh');
  // And whatever you wanna load fresh, after the AJAX call is completed.
});
```

Comment: I think problem is with tabs method, ajaxComplete is working well as expected to be triggered after content is loaded but tabs are not working still